# adding json objects to array php

Tags: php, arrays, json

Im having a problem working with JSON objects and PHP.
The Edited_Players JSON object can have one or more child objects as shown below

Here it is with 2 child objects

```
"Team_Updates": {
    "Edited_Players": [
        {
            "position": "flanker",
            "last_name": "mowbrayfg",
            "id": 3,
            "first_name": "fchris",
            "weight": "weight",
            "height": "high"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "last_name": "gg",
            "position": "gg",
            "first_name": "ffgyvvyvy",
            "height": "cttvyv",
            "weight": "gg"
        }
    ]
},
```

Here it is with 1 single child object:

```
Team_Updates": {
    "Edited_Players": 
        {
            "position": "flanker",
            "last_name": "mowbrayfg",
            "id": 3,
            "first_name": "fchris",
            "weight": "weight",
            "height": "high"
        }
               }
```

The problem is when I execute the below code, if the Edited_Players JSON object is of size 2 then the for loop will execute twice and that is correct. BUT if the Edited_Players JSON object is of size 1 then the loop executes 6 times.

This is because if Edited_Players > 1 then it is populated by an array but if = 1 then it just counts the single objects within.

how can make change so that the code sees  {position,last_name,id,first_name,weight,height] as 1 object?

```
if(isset($editedPlayersObj)){

    $epIDArray = array();
    $epFnameArray = array();
    $epSnameArray = array();
    $epHieghtArray = array();
    $epWeightArray = array();
    $epPosArray = array();

    for ($x=0; $x<count($editedPlayersObj); $x++)
      {
        $epFnameArray[$x] = $editedPlayersObj[$x]['first_name'];
        $epSnameArray[$x] = $editedPlayersObj[$x]['last_name'];
        $epIDArray[$x] = $editedPlayersObj[$x]['id'];
        $epHieghtArray[$x] = $editedPlayersObj[$x]['weight'];
        $epWeightArray[$x] = $editedPlayersObj[$x]['height'];
        $epPosArray[$x] = $editedPlayersObj[$x]['position'];

        // insert into database the above 
      }
```

Comment: It's better to rebuild source json properly.

Comment: @u_mulder could you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the constructed JSON.  I would think that there should ALWAYS be an array wrapping one or more `Edited_Players" object(s).  In your second case there is not, you so end up iterating the properties of the single object provided.

If you have no control over the JSON, then you should detect whether the value to `Edited_Players` is an array or an object and work with it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, Im using the 'is_array' method but it still returns true when Edited_Players is an object

Comment: '$editedPlayersObj = $updates['Edited_Players'];'
'if (is_array($editedPlayersObj)){...'

Comment: @ChrisMowbray Are you using the option to force associative arrays when calling `json_decode()`?  Like `json_decode($json, true)`? If so, you may want to consider not using that such that only numerically indexed arrays are decoded to arrays and object representations are turned into objects, not associative arrays.  In such a case, that object should be decoded to `stdClass` PHP object.

Comment: Yes that the way I am doing it. can you point me in the direction of how to do it another way?

Comment: @ChrisMowbray Just remove the `true` flag to make it like `json_decode($json)`.  You will also need to change you variable references in the loop to be like `$editedPlayersObj[$x]->first_name` since you would be dealing with objects.  Of course the BEST solution would be to just change the way the JSON is created to always wrap the value in an array (if you have control over that).  That way you could with with either objects or associative arrays as you desire since you would no longer have the problem of trying to detect an array vs. object.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question, you might have better luck using [json_decode](https://www.php.net/json_decode). This will allow you to access each return value as an object.